# Inserting a formula containing variable into a cell using a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba macro that copies the current sheet and renames it with the current date that works fine, now I want it to put a formula in cell B22, the formula that I want is:

```
  Current Sheet       Previous Sheet
='08 May 2013'!B18 - '01-04-2013'!B18
```

I have been trying to get this code to work, but it is putting it in as a string not a formula
 i.e.   = ('[08 May 2013 !R2C18] - [  12 May 2013 !R2C18])

```
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim activeSheet_name As String
Dim shtName As Integer
Dim activeShtName As Integer
shtName = Sheets.Count - 1
activeShtName = Sheets.Count
sheet_name = Sheets(shtName).Name
activeSheet_name = Sheets(activeShtName).Name
Sheets(activeSheet_name).Select
Range("B22").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = " = ('[" & sheet_name & " !R2C18] - [  " & activeSheet_name & " !R2C18])"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong.  Try it in Excel first, then copy the text of the formula and compare to the text that your last line of code above is producing.  Change your VBA code to this:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & sheet_name & "'!R18C2-'" & activeSheet_name & "'!R18C2"

Note the use of FormulaR1C1.  Basically you need to surround the sheet names with single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but that didn’t work I’m not sure you understand what I am trying to do, each sheet as the date as the sheet name held in the variables sheet_name and activeSheet_name
I need the formula to subtract the value in cell B18 on sheet 08 May 2013 from cell B18 on sheet 12 May 2013 and put the answer in cell B22 on sheet 12 May 2013
Hope this makes it a bit clearer

Comment: Ok, I have changed the answer above.  You could work out exactly what the string needs to be by doing it in Excel first, copying the string and pasting into VBA, then replacing the references to the sheets with your sheet name variables.

Comment: Thanks steveo40 that worked a treat, I’ve been stuck on that for ages thanks a lot

Comment: No worries, glad it's working.  Please mark it as an answer if it's all working nicely now.  Cheers

Comment: The string wasn’t the problem it’s knowing the syntax can you recommend any good books